# Events from iframes or webviews in electron window

Tags: javascript, events, webview, electron, event-handling

We recieve our pages from server and to avoid cross origin issues i replace all my iframes to webviews
So after some time we recieved a task where we need to show mouse coordinates when clicking on window, and everyting works fine except pages with webviews, it cannot show click in area of webview

Please help me to resolve the issue

From start i tried to implement simple click operation on document in renderer process

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', (e) => showMouseCoordsMessage(e);
});

const showMouseCoordsMessage = (event) => {
  const { clientX, clientY } = event;
  console.log({ clientX, clientY });
}
```

but as i mentioned earlier it raise some issues with webviews

after that i tried to create invisible overlay for whole window, but it also raised problems with clickble content in webviews that user might to click from time to time

the last approach i tried was injecting js code in webview from start like this:

```js
  webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
    webview.openDevTools();
    webview.preload = '${preloadPath()}'
    webview.executeJavaScript("document.addEventListener('click', () => require('electron').ipcRenderer.sendSync('getMousePosition'))")
  })
```

but in this case this it cannot find ipcRenderer or other issues that i still do not solved